Точки в прямой речи
Ситуация такая: рассказчик в прямой речи рассказывает о себе, а потом  в прямую речь вставляет диалог между собой своими товарищами. Корректор утверждает, что в прямой речи после восклика и кавычек не нужно ставить точку.   В данном случае после слов "Победа", "тратить" и "взвод". Я не согласна. Как нужно правильно и какие правила это подтверждают?                                      «…Война для меня закончилась в Венгрии. Помню девятое мая сорок пятого. Мы стоим в обороне возле озера Балатон. Прибегает посыльный из штаба нашего эскадрона с криком: «Победа!!!» Хлопцы тоже закричали, стали в воздух палить. Я, конечно, обрадовался, но все же сказал: «Хватить патроны даром тратить!» Мне тогда командир: «Иванов!» – «Я!» – «Веди взвод!» Построились три полка нашей дивизии: номера 43, 45, 47, провели митинг. «Главный враг сдался! Победа!» – объявил командующий».

Правильно:
Прибегает посыльный из штаба нашего эскадрона с криком: «Победа!!!»
Я, конечно, обрадовался, но все же сказал: «Хватить патроны даром тратить!»
Мне тогда командир: «Иванов!» – «Я!» – «Веди взвод!»
«Главный враг сдался! Победа!» – объявил командующий.
Пояснение
В конце прямой речи ставится только один знак: восклицательный знак (или вопросительный знак, многоточие) до кавычек, а точка после кавычек (если прямая речь повествовательная).  В вашем случае точка не нужна, ставится только восклицательный знак.
Примечание. Постановка обоих знаков возможна в таком предложении: Он/я сказал, что «Хватить патроны даром тратить!».  Точка дополнительно  ставится в косвенной речи в форме СПП (сложноподчиненного предложения с союзом ЧТО). Но этот случай характерен для цитирования, если приводится дословное высказывание.
ОБЩЕЕ ПРАВИЛО
Розенталь § 48. Прямая речь после слов автора

Вопросительный и восклицательный знаки, а также многоточие ставятся перед закрывающими кавычками, а точка — после них.

Наконец я ей сказал: «Хочешь, пойдём прогуляться на вал?» (Л.); Лёжа на тюке и плача, он дёргал руками и ногами и шептал: «Мама! Мама!» (Ч.); Закричали: «Двоих… Санитары… Гляди, гляди — ещё летит… Лезь под вагоны…» (А. Т.), Хозяйка очень часто обращалась к Чичикову со словами: «Вы очень мало взяли». (Г.)
ПРИМЕЧАНИЕ
Постановка точки после восклицательного знака и кавычек возможна при цитировании в форме придаточного предложения.
Письмовник
б) ставят точку, если цитата **не является 
самостоятельным предложением,** а выступает **как 
часть придаточного** (даже если перед закрывающими 
кавычками стоит **многоточие, вопросительный или 
восклицательный знак)**:

Б. Л. Пастернак подчеркивал, что «самое ясное, запоминающееся и важное в искусстве есть его возникновенье...».
Также у Розенталя: § 56. Многоточие при цитатах,  пункт 2
 2. Если цитата, заканчивающаяся многоточием, не 
 является самостоятельным предложением, то после 
 нее ставится точка:

 М. В. Ломоносов писал, что «красота, великолепие, 
 сила и богатство российского языка явствует 
 довольно из книг, в прошлые века писанных…».

ПОЧЕМУ ТАК?

Сложное предложение с прямой речью при классическом оформлении состоит из двух частей (сочинительная бессоюзная связь). При этом прямая речь является самостоятельной частью и имеет собственное оформление, где отражаются особенности произношения для повествовательного,  вопросительного и др. вариантов. Поэтому точка при наличии других знаков не ставится.

При цитировании  в виде СПП прямая речь не является самостоятельной и входит в  придаточное предложение, а точка обозначает повествовательный характер всего СПП и ставится на его конце.



Sharon, спасибо за ответ. Я не филолог. Объясните, пожалуйста, простым языком "Постановка точки после восклицательного знака и кавычек возможна при цитировании в форме придаточного предложения". В моем приведенном выше примере, точки нужны или нет? Они (предложения), являются придаточными?

Извините, моя неточность при оформлении, я дополнила ответ. В вашем случае точки нет. // Обычно вопрос о точке задают именно для косвенной речи с союзом ЧТО, когда возможны оба знака. Вот я и увлеклась сбором этой информации)   То есть все  "примечание" к вашему случаю не относится.  Это дополнительная информация. Спасибо за вопрос.
